# Bootstrap 3 contact modal is not showing up

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, modal-dialog, contacts

I have a small contact modal on my website that does not appear. It was working before, but I must have changed something and now it won't work.

I've looked over it multiple times and I can't figure out why it's not working.

HTML:

```
<a href="contact"><span data-toggle="modal">Contact</span></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Contact the Developers</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="contact-msg" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> 
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `data-target` attribute. Plus, you shouldn't be linking to a page when you want to open a modal ;)

`<a href="#"><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact">Contact</span></a>`

Should fix this. See http://www.bootply.com/UED0aevXsG

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the php for this would you? As in how I would actually make this form email me?

Comment: What you need is a form processor. http://webdesy.com/how-to-create-html-php-contact-form-part-2/ is a simple enough tutorial on how to build one. I typically use one within a CMS.